# Can Perl scripts be used to work with different file formats?

Tags: xml, perl, pdf, file-io, ms-word

I haven't done much with Perl and was trying to find out if you can work with different types of file formats with it, besides text files?  As in `pdf`, `doc`, `xls`, `xml`.  Also, if it can be done does it require [CPAN](http://search.cpan.org/) modules or just with the basic Perl scripts?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, there are [CPAN modules](http://search.cpan.org/) to manipulate (or at least read) many different file formats.

A basic Perl script CAN do it, but then you're going to have to figure out the file format yourself. E.g., if you're doing to manipulate a JPEG image and want to add a watermark, you'd have to write your own JPEG decompressor, your own bitmap rasterizer, your own font parser/rasterizer, and eventually a JPEG compressor to save the resulting watermarked image.

You'll very quickly get into the thousands of lines of code for this

… or you could just install a couple CPAN modules and get it done in about 5 or 6 lines of code.

Answer (score 3):

[CPAN](http://search.cpan.org/) is your friend. You'll find modules for most document types you might encounter.

And, yes, you'd need libraries to deal with specific file formats in all languages.

- [XML](http://search.cpan.org/search?query=xml&mode=module)
- [Spreadsheets](http://search.cpan.org/search?query=spreadsheet&mode=module)
- [PDF](http://search.cpan.org/search?query=pdf&mode=module)
- [HTML](http://search.cpan.org/search?query=html&mode=module)

[etc etc etc](http://search.cpan.org/).